# Querying Temp table in RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table called `packets` in Redshift. I want to create a temp table called `tmp_packet_size` as part of the session and  generate analytics. However, I am getting the output `ResultSet returned after update count`. Below is my query:

```
CREATE table #tmp_packet_size as (SELECT * from packets limit 10); 
SELECT * FROM #tmp_packet_size

RESULT -> ResultSet returned after update count.
```

I have permission to create temp tables.